# How to import ng-bootstrap in shared angular module available through npm

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am developing an angular module using ng-bootstrap. I want to import and use it as a shared component in other angular applications that do not use ng-bootstrap.

When I import it into the other application, ng-bootstrap breaks the styling of the other app. It is not isolated inside my exposed component (I used `ViewEncaplusation.Native`). Default `ViewEncapsulation` (Emulated) also doesn't work.

Here is how I decorated my shared component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-testcomponent',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
      '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss',
      './app.component.scss'
   ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class TestComponent {...}</code>
```